# Convert week to date spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string in the format of

```
"5/02/2016" // d/ww/yyyy
```

that I want to convert to a format of

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

I have tried the following

```
val df = Seq((1L, "5/02/2016"), (2L, "aaa")).toDF("id", "date")
val ts = unix_timestamp($"date", "d/ww/yyyy").cast("timestamp")
df.withColumn("ts", ts).show(2, false)
```

I get

```
//output
+---+---------+-----------+
|id |date     |ts         |
+---+---------+-----------+
|1  |5/02/2016|2016-01-05 |
|2  |aaa      |null       |
+---+---------+-----------+
```

When I want

```
//expected
+---+---------+-----------+
|id |date     |ts         |
+---+---------+-----------+
|1  |5/02/2016|2016-01-19 |
|2  |aaa      |null       |
+---+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Isn't your output and expected result are same?

Comment: `d` is day of month, if you want day of week use `u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting dates is a tricky business. In this case, leap years prevent us from mapping day of year directly to month of year and day of month.

In Scala, we may use the java.util.GregorianCalendar:

```
def weekToDate(weekStr: String) = {
  val (day, week, year) = {
    val arr = weekStr.split("/").map(_.toInt)
    (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))
  }
  val cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar()
  cal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, year)
  cal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7 * week + day)
  new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime)
}
weekToDate("5/02/2016") // res0: String = 2016-01-19

// Leap year example
weekToDate("4/08/2016") // res1: String = 2016-02-29
weekToDate("4/08/2017") // res2: String = 2017-03-01
```

Putting it all together:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def weekToDate(weekStr: String) = {
  val (day, week, year) = {
    val arr = weekStr.split("/").map(_.toInt)
    (arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))
  }
  val cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar()
  cal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, year)
  cal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7 * week + day)
  new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime)
}

val df = Seq((1L, "5/02/2016"), (2L, "4/8/2016")).toDF("id", "date").select("date")

val wfn: String => String = weekToDate(_)
val tsUDF=udf(wfn)
df.withColumn("ts", tsUDF('date)).show(2, false)

+---------+----------+
|date     |ts        |
+---------+----------+
|5/02/2016|2016-01-19|
|4/8/2016 |2016-02-29|
+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @puhlen, day of week should be `u`, not `d` (see [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

```
val df = Seq((1L, "5/02/2016"), (2L, "aaa")).toDF("id", "date")
val ts = unix_timestamp($"date", "u/ww/yyyy").cast("timestamp")
df.withColumn("ts", ts).show(2, false)

+---+---------+---------------------+
|id |date     |ts                   |
+---+---------+---------------------+
|1  |5/02/2016|2016-01-08 00:00:00.0|
|2  |aaa      |null                 |
+---+---------+---------------------+
```

Please also note that you shouldn't expect `5/02/2016` will be arithmetically the same as day `2 x 7 + 5` of `2016`. You should actually check the 2016 calendar, and the Friday in its 2nd week is in fact January 8.